Go to definition in current window if split windows for the same buffer
When I opened two split windows for the same buffer and called vim.lsp.buf.definition, if the symbol definition is in the same file, it would always jump to definition in the first window.
Is there a way to jump to definition in current window instead of the first window?

How exactly are you calling the function? If I open a file, split it, and then type :lua vim.lsp.buf.definition(), I jump in whichever window I am currently in while the other remains as-is.

@carschandler I am using Lazyvim, and I realised it's using reuse_win to jump to definition. Setting it to false solve the problem! Thanks for your help.
